# Getting null instead of List of strings flutter json

Tags: json, flutter, api, http, dart

I'm making a recipes app that request the data form edamam Api and shows it in a listview.builder i have home screen class that make the request and shows the data

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/info_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/recipes.dart';
import 'dart:convert' as cnv;
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeScreen createState() => _HomeScreen();
}

class _HomeScreen extends State<HomeScreen> {
  //List<MissedIngredients>? missedIngredients;
  List<Recipe>? results;
  int path = 0;
  int? numberOfIngredants;
  int numberOfRequestedRecipes = 3;
  String? foodName;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    getData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Food recipe api'),
      ),
      body: results == null
          ? Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            )
          : ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Card(
                    child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(results![index].label.toString()),
                  leading: Image.network(results![index].image.toString()),
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      foodName = results![index].label.toString();
                      print(foodName);
                    });
                  },
                ));
              },
              itemCount: numberOfRequestedRecipes),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add_circle),
        onPressed: () {
          numberOfRequestedRecipes = numberOfRequestedRecipes + 10;
          setState(() {
            getData();
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> getData() async {
    http.Response res = await http.get(Uri.parse(
        'https://api.edamam.com/api/recipes/v2?type=public&q=pizza&app_id=4dd9eafd&app_key=f2fa2c38ec16944f522dc9b734424cf4'));
    print(res.body);
    List<dynamic> body = cnv.jsonDecode(res.body)['hits'];
    results = body.map((dynamic item) => Recipe.fromJson(item)).toList();
    setState(() {});
  }
}
```

and a recipes class that analyze the data so i can show it in the home screen

```
class recipes {
  int ?from;
  int ?to;
  int ?count;
  Links ?lLinks;
  List<Hits> ?hits;

  recipes({this.from, this.to, this.count, this.lLinks, this.hits});

  recipes.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    from = json['from'];
    to = json['to'];
    count = json['count'];
    lLinks = json['_links'] != null ? new Links.fromJson(json['_links']) : null;
    if (json['hits'] != null) {
      hits = <Hits>[];
      json['hits'].forEach((v) {
        hits!.add(new Hits.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['from'] = this.from;
    data['to'] = this.to;
    data['count'] = this.count;
    if (this.lLinks != null) {
      data['_links'] = this.lLinks!.toJson();
    }
    if (this.hits != null) {
      data['hits'] = this.hits!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Links {
  Next ? next;

  Links({required this.next});

  Links.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    next = (json['next'] != null ? new Next.fromJson(json['next']) : null)!;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.next != null) {
      data['next'] = this.next!.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Next {
  String ?href;
  String ?title;

  Next({this.href, this.title});

  Next.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    href = json['href'];
    title = json['title'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['href'] = this.href;
    data['title'] = this.title;
    return data;
  }
}

class Hits {
  Recipe ? recipe;
  Links ? lLinks;

  Hits({this.recipe, this.lLinks});

  Hits.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    recipe =
        json['recipe'] != null ? new Recipe.fromJson(json['recipe']) : null;
    lLinks = json['_links'] != null ? new Links.fromJson(json['_links']) : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.recipe != null) {
      data['recipe'] = this.recipe!.toJson();
    }
    if (this.lLinks != null) {
      data['_links'] = this.lLinks!.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Recipe {
  String ?uri;
  String ?label;
  String ?image;
  String ?source;
  String ?url;
  String ?shareAs;
  int ?yield;
  

  Recipe(
      {this.uri,
      this.label,
      this.image,
      this.source,
      this.url,
      this.shareAs,
      this.yield,
      });

  Recipe.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    uri = json['uri'];
    label = json['label'];
    image = json['image'];
    source = json['source'];
    url = json['url'];
    shareAs = json['shareAs'];
    yield = json['yield'];
    
    }
  

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['uri'] = this.uri;
    data['label'] = this.label;
    data['image'] = this.image;
    data['source'] = this.source;
    data['url'] = this.url;
    data['shareAs'] = this.shareAs;
    data['yield'] = this.yield;
    
    return data;
  }
}

class Ingredients {
  String? text;
  double? weight;
  String? foodCategory;
  String? foodId;
  String? image;

  Ingredients(
      {this.text, this.weight, this.foodCategory, this.foodId, this.image});

  Ingredients.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    text = json['text'];
    weight = json['weight'];
    foodCategory = json['foodCategory'];
    foodId = json['foodId'];
    image = json['image'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['text'] = this.text;
    data['weight'] = this.weight;
    data['foodCategory'] = this.foodCategory;
    data['foodId'] = this.foodId;
    data['image'] = this.image;
    return data;
  }
}
```

but when I run the app all I get is a null value so what is the problem
thank you for your valuable time!

Answer (score 0):

Hi the Simplest Solution for your problem is to use a [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

If you use the Widget build,
the  method will run simultaneous with the init method,due to which you might receive null values even when values are in process of fetching . So use a future builder of type bool and use only when there's data !=null.